# I have a piece of code that i dont understand why it uses shl instruction when creating an array using malloc

Tags: x86, malloc

I'm trying to understand this piece of code which uses shell instruction(SHL) when dynamically allocating memory to a 1D array in x86(MASM assembly). I want to know the reason behind the person to use shl instruction.

[code fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFHwe.png)

Answer (score 2):

Shifting something left once is the same as multiplying it by 2; and shifting something left N times is the same as multiplying it by 2**N; but shifting is typically faster than an actual multiplication.

For the code you've shown; it's multiplying `n` by `sizeof(int)`. Because `sizeof(int)` happens to be 4, that means it can shift left twice (`shl eax,2`) instead of doing a (more expensive) multiplication.

Comment: The comment for the line with the arrow even explains it: `; eax <-- n * 4    (size of int is 4).`